# Logging reserved words/characters

Tags: c#, string-interpolation

I have a `*.resx` string that looks like this:

`Failed to deserialize an object of type '{0}' from the following string:{1}{2}`

This string is being used to log such kinds of errors and currently, the logging statement looks like this:

```
_logger.LogError(Resources.FailedToDeserialize, typeof(MyType).Name, Environment.NewLine, invalidJsonString);
```

As you can see - I need to pass `Environment.NewLine` each time to display my logs correctly for any OS.

I am curious are there any reserved string interpolation words/characters to insert such values?

For example, my string could look like this:

`Failed to deserialize an object of type '{0}' from the following string:{NewLine}{2}`

And my logging statement would be a bit simpler:

```
_logger.LogError(Resources.FailedToDeserialize, typeof(MyType).Name, invalidJsonString);
```

Comment: In the Visual Studio resource editor, you can use `Shift`+`Return` to insert a line-break inside a value. But that will use the newline character from your current OS, rather than the OS your application eventually runs on.

Comment: Also, [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) is something completely different to the code you're using in your question.

Comment: One thing you can do is some form of pre processing on application start up by reading the resource file, replacing your keyword of choice i.e `{NewLine}` with `Environment.NewLine` and then use that cached string for the entirety of your application life time.

Comment: So, you have a json string that failed deserialization. Any chance of some strange  character in that string that messes up the formatting of the log library used?

Comment: @RichardDeeming, guess you're right. I will change the title.

Comment: @Steve, well, that's a good point actually. I think I should not log the invalid string itself. But this does not answer the question. Such a technique could be useful in other cases.

Comment: @KieranDevlin, that might be a bit overhead. If there are no built-in functionalities for this - it does not worth manual implementation.

Comment: @ArthurEdgarov There would be zero overhead. You're precomputing the string upon startup and storing the result just like you're doing with the embedded resource. Its also hardly any work to implement at all...

Comment: @KieranDevlin, could you post an answer then? I mark it as correct tomorrow if there would be no answers with built-in features. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is some form of pre processing on application start up by reading the resource file, replacing your keyword of choice i.e `{NewLine}` with `Environment.NewLine` and then use that cached string for the entirety of your application life time.

You can make the fields `readonly` and do some reflection magic to set the value but this example should give you an idea of how to solve your current problem.

```cs
public static class LoggingMessageTemplates
{
    //Reference your resource here e.g Resource.FailedToDeserialize
    public static string FailedToDeserialize = "Resource.Something {NewLine} Something Else";
    
    public static void FormatMessages() 
    {
        var stringFields = typeof(LoggingMessageTemplates)
            .GetFields()
            .Where(x => x.FieldType == typeof(string));
        
        foreach(var field in stringFields) 
        {
            if (field.GetValue(null) is not string fieldValue)
            {
                throw new InvalidCastException($"Failed to cast field {field.Name} to string.");
            }
            
            field.SetValue(null, fieldValue.Replace("{NewLine}", Environment.NewLine));
        }
    }
}

//On application startup, format the resources to use the Environment.NewLine char of the current system.
LoggingMessageTemplates.FormatMessages();

//When logging, reference the LoggingMessageTemplates class rather than the direct resource.
Console.WriteLine(LoggingMessageTemplates.FailedToDeserialize);

//i.e
_logger.LogError(LoggingMessageTemplates.FailedToDeserialize, typeof(MyType).Name, invalidJsonString);
```